# Get notification message when data submit it to the server database

Tags: android, notifications

I am very new to the notification concept in android.

Here I want to know the best approach to get notification message, 
whenever users of my app sends data to the server database. 
I want to get notification message in my mobile.

The user 123 submitted data, please check your database. This kind of
notification I want it my android app.

How can I achieve this task. Please brief about the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Easy Way]**

Use emails. Whenever a user sends you notification, you can simply send a mail to an account already configured on your (hopefully) android phone. This way you get through the task without spending any "extra" time handling notifications. You just have to enable sync from your android account and it will do the rest of the work for you.
Most email applications handle the sync and notification themselves.

**[Not So Easy Way]**

Implement a GCM Push notification system. Whenever your server gets some message, send a push notification to your mobile that user 123 submitted data. On the android end, make an application that will handle that push notification for you. This is the thing you need : http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

*If you just want a static notification, I will recommend the easy way. There is no point spending so much effort building a system with GCM just for this, unless you want it branded with your name*

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will check GCM notification.

Comment: If you like the answer you can always select an answer and make the question "answered". This might come in handy http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I think GCM Push Notification will be efficient and reliable way that you want to achieve. try this..
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/